# Accessing object with square brackets in typescript

Tags: typescript

Simplified version of what I'm trying to accomplish.

```
const colors = {
  red: "#8b0000",
  green: "#008b00",
}

const logColor = (color: string) => {
  console.log(colors[color])
}
```

This error comes from inside the console.log()

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{ red: string; green: string; }'.

No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{ red: string; green: string; }'.
```

What do I need to do to fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `keyof typeof colors` instead of `string`.

```
const colors = {
  red: "#8b0000",
  green: "#008b00",
}

const logColor = <T extends keyof typeof colors>(color: T) => {
  console.log(colors[color])
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That helped. But in the process I realised I need to ask a different question about this :D